# IconButton extends the dimensions of it's container

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-ui, expand

I have this React component:

```
const ItemsOverview = ({ details, classes }) => {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            details.items.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.itemBatchNumber}>
                        <ExpansionPanel>
                            <ExpansionPanelSummary className={classes.PanelSummary} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                                <IconButton className={classes.button} aria-label="Print" onClick={DoStuff}><PrintIcon /></IconButton>
                                &nbsp;
                                <Typography className={classes.heading}>My panel title</Typography>
                            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                                My Content
                            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                        </ExpansionPanel>
                    </div>
                );
            })
        }
        </div>
    );
};
```

The styling of that IconButton is minimal right now:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    button: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    }
});
```

Without the IconButton, I get a panel of acceptable height:

[image: This looks good]

With the IconButton, the panel area is enlarged quite a bit:

[image]

> What can I do to make the panel with the IconButton look like it did without it?

Obviously setting margin and padding doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try using the [Icon](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/style/icons/) component instead of IconButton?

Answer (score 2):

The extra padding is coming from the `ExpansionPanelSummary` component, not the `IconButton`, which is why setting the button to have `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` isn't having any effect.

You need to override the styling on the `ExpansionPanelSummary` so that your button doesn't add extra space in the header:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  noPadding: {
    margin: '0',
  },
});

<ExpansionPanelSummary classes={{content: classes.noPadding}} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
```

Then, because there won't be any padding around your heading text anymore, you need to add padding back to the `Typography` component:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  padded: {
    margin: '12px 0',
  },
});

<Typography className={classes.padded}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import ExpansionPanel, {
  ExpansionPanelSummary,
} from 'material-ui/ExpansionPanel';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from 'material-ui-icons/ExpandMore';
import PrintIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Print';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton'; 

const styles = theme => ({
  noPadding: {
    margin: '0',
  },
  padded: {
    margin: '12px 0',
  },
});

function SimpleExpansionPanel(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary classes={{content: classes.noPadding}} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <IconButton component="div" tabIndex="-1" aria-label="Print"> <PrintIcon /> </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.padded}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleExpansionPanel.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleExpansionPanel);
```